# why am i getting this TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I have this dictionary

```
response = {'body': '{"error": "Validation error'}','statusCode': 400}
```

i want to get the element "error"

```
print(response["body"]["error"])
```

but this gives me

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

where am i going wrong

Comment: The value for `'body'` seems to be a **string**, not a dict.

Comment: Echoing @j1-lee, the single quotes outside the curly braces make this a string. Is this the exact code? There's a quote mismatch here.

Comment: The `’body’` field is a string, it’s not a dict key called `error`.

Answer (score 2):

You issue is with the superfluous `'`s:

```
$ python test.py
  File "C:\Users\pdunn\Downloads\test\test.py", line 1
    response = {'body': '{"error": "Validation error'}','statusCode': 400}
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Remove them and it'll work:

```
response = {"body": {"error": "Validation error"}, "statusCode": 400}
print(response["body"]["error"])
```

```
$ python test.py
Validation error
```

Also, as advice, be consistent with `'` and `"`.

Comment: this is the generated Api response so there are quotes, response = {'body': '{"error": "Validation error'}','statusCode': 400} this is the response, please tell me how to get the value "error"

Comment: Then, that's a misformed response, the json string is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Probably `response["body"]` is a string (not a dictionary as you are treating it as).

Try printing its type with:

```
print(type(response["body"]))
```

If it is `str`, then you can make it a dict with the `json` module:

```
import json
body = json.loads(response["error"])
print(body["error"])
```